# Heroku Internal Server Error when attempting to send an email using Mailgun

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, rest-client, mailgun

I have a simple Ruby Sinatra app which allows users to request a new password - using Mailgun to trigger an email. It works perfectly well in development (localhost) but returns 'Internal Server Error' on Heroku. I'm still new to debugging Heroku so have looked at $ heroku logs but this doesn't appear to tell me anything of use. All Mailgun ENVs are correctly set under heroku:config.

Still a newbie to StackOverflow so please let me know if I can clarify my question further/provide more info....

App url - http://chitter-challenge.herokuapp.com/users/reset_password

Repo - https://github.com/timrobertson0122/chitter-challenge

Code snippet -

```
require 'rest-client'

class MailgunWrapper

def send_email_to user
api_key = ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY']
api_url = "https://api:#{api_key}@api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxf59a3be327d54fd79069be7d347b9af4.mailgun.org"

RestClient::Request.execute(
  url: api_url + '/messages',
  method: :post,
  payload: {
    from: 'postmaster@sandboxf59a3be327d54fd79069be7d347b9af4.mailgun.org',
    to: user.email,
    subject: 'This is subject',
    text: 'This is text',
    html: 'https://chitter-challenge.herokuapp.com/users/reset_password' + user.password_token,
    multipart: true
  },
  headers: {
    "h:X-My-Header" => 'www/mailgun-email-send'
  },
  verify_ssl: false
)
 end

end
```

Gist of Heroku logs output - https://gist.github.com/timrobertson0122/fa79c18f66866ee180a3#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: you can see the errors with `heroku logs`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As mentioned the logs don't appear to be telling me anything of use - is there something specific I should be looking for?

Comment: can you include a gist or similar with your heroku logs?

Comment: @silvabox - have edited the origin post to include a gist - thanks!

Comment: That's not showing all the stack trace. Try `heroku logs -n 1500`

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu - I've updated the gist with that output. It's given me these lines, which I'm currently trying to understand  `2015-08-13T16:12:21.041780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/reset_password" host=chitter-challenge.herokuapp.com request_id=7d3be567-5a77-4eea-9f29-c8222c955cca fwd="82.24.206.127" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=180ms status=500 bytes=326
2015-08-13T16:12:21.034754+00:00 app[web.1]: 2015-08-13 16:12:21 - RestClient::ResourceNotFound - 404 Resource Not Found:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can see for that to happen in your case is that your maligun domain `'sandboxf59a3be327d54fd79069be7d347b9af4'` might be incorrect. Have you checked your dashboard to see that the numbers actually match with your real domain. I've tried locally and getting the domain wrong is the only way I can see to get that error since the rest of the url is properly formatted.

Also you can try going here `https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html` which, if logged in, should give you an example of how to run a properly formatted post request with curl including your correct credentials. See if that works and if your params in the ruby code match what that says.